# Auto-closing for single quote in vim

Tags: vim

I've setup auto-completions for parentheses and double quotes following the directions on [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters).

The auto closing for single quotes is a bit more complicated, however. When dealing with single quotes, I have to check if it is used as an apostrophe or as a quote. The criteria for an apostrophe would perhaps be when the single quote is immediately preceded by an alphabet or number.

How do I implement this setting in my vimrc?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the details of that algorithm depend on the type of text (programming languages vs. prose) and individual tradeoffs. I'd recommend to study how the 6+ plugins listed on the [mentioned page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters#Plugins) handle that; the different approaches are probably quite instructive.

Maybe you'll also find information how some popular IDEs implement this (at least for the open Eclipse, this information should be available).

Answer (score 0):

Using this will help

`ino ' ''<left>`

If you dont't want completion <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> need to be typed prior to `'`.

Not exactly what you are looking but a way to work without complex logic at the cost of extra key stroke